# How do I sort a list of numbers based on the last two digits?

Tags: python, sorting

Is it possible? I have to sort it without the sort functions but I want to see if I can sort it based on the last two digits.

Comment: Can yoy give an expected input and output?

Comment: Use `lambda n: n % 100` as the key?

Comment: so you want sort without the sort function? it is possible, but this feels like a homework question. Have you written any code yet?

Comment: The title says "with the built-in sort functions".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in `list.sort` method or `sorted` function with a `key` function. The function `lambda n: abs(n) % 100` gets the last two digits:

```py
>>> nums = [99, 888, 7777, 66666, 555555]
>>> sorted(nums, key=lambda n: abs(n) % 100)
[555555, 66666, 7777, 888, 99]
```

The `abs` makes it work for negative numbers as well. If your list has no negative numbers, you can just write `n % 100`.

If you are sorting using your own algorithm, one way is to follow the "[decorate, sort, undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)" pattern: build a list of pairs where the first component is the sort key, then write your sorting algorithm as normal, then extract the original values to return the sorted list.

```py
def sort_by_last_two_digits(nums):
    nums = [(abs(n) % 100, n) for n in nums]

    # do the sorting normally

    return [n for _, n in nums]
```

Comment: Bit shorter/faster for the no-negatives case: `key=100 .__rmod__`.

Comment: I mean without the sort built-in functions

Comment: Well, that's the exact opposite of what you wrote in your question: *"How do I sort a list of numbers based on the last two digits with the built-in sort functions"*

Comment: I meant without my apologies

Comment: OK, I've edited to cover that case; in the future, please be careful when writing a question to ask what you actually want to ask.